# Negate the statement ‘If $x^2+2x+1=0$, then $x=-1$’.

Tags: real-analysis

> Negate the statement ‘If $x^2+2x+1=0$, then $x=-1$’.

I am trying to solve this question using truth tables but no luck. I would appreciate help.[image][image]

##### Attempt

$x^2+2x+1 = 0 \implies x = -1$

Let $P(x)$ be a statement depending on a variable. Then ,
\begin{align}
&\text{not(}\exists x \text{ such that } P(x)) \\
&= \forall x , \text{ not } P(x) \\
&= x \in \mathbb R , x^2+2x+1 \neq 0 
\end{align}

Comment: Well, there are two ways to negate an implication. Either take the converse or the inverse. Which one do you prefer?

Comment: Neither the converse nor the inverse of an implication is equivalent to the negation of that implication.

Comment: First express $A\Rightarrow B$ as $\neg A \lor B$, then use De Morgan.

Comment: Don Thousand- I prefer converse

Comment: The converse and inverse of an implication are equivvalent to each other; as pointed out by Lee, neither are actually equivalent to its negation.  You claim to have tried truth tables; what else have you tried?

Comment: Can anyone please show me the steps , I am really confused....

Comment: No, we're not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: The _real_ trouble here is that one cannot really tell whether the claim to be negated is $x^2+2x+1=0\Rightarrow x=-1$ or $\forall x(x^2+2x+1=0\Rightarrow x=-1)$. The distinction between these is very often left to context in ordinary prose, but their negations would be expressed differently! So to pick the right one, we would need to look at contextual clues from the material you got the exercise from.

Comment: I tried solving it , the solution is uploaded above .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe negation is not the optimal word to phrase your question.

The important part to get here is that $A \Longrightarrow B$ does not imply $ B \Longrightarrow A$ which in casual conversations sometimes happens.
But what you can say is that if $A$ is true and $A \Longrightarrow B$ then B must be true.

On the other hand if $B$ is not true (we write it as $\neg B$) then $A$ can't be true since otherwise the implication would come into play. So it is still true that $$\neg B \Longrightarrow \neg A$$ is true but this is not a "negation" but a reformulation of the statement.

In a more strict way one could say:
$$ \forall x : x^2+2x+1=0 \Longrightarrow x=-1
$$
is true so a negation would be the statement "false" or
$$0=1$$

which I don't think you meant.

Also we as community like to see that one made an effort to solve it or provides the steps where he/she struggles, so if you included what your thoughtprocess was our help could be taylored more towards you.

Comment: Well, the quantified claim is true in $\mathbb R$, but it's false in, for example, $\mathbb R[X]/\langle X^2\rangle$ (where $X-1$ is another root of the polynomial). Even though it's doubtful that the OP has heard of the latter ring, I think it is almost certain that the exercise wants them to practice negating the _logical form_ of the claim rather than bothering about its _arithmetic content_.

Comment: oh yes. Probably not talking about fields of fraction.